# Closed prime ideal in $C[0, 1]$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ra.rings-and-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras, prime-ideals

I know that maximal ideals of $C[0, 1]$ corresponds to singleton. Also, using Zorn's lemma one can construct a prime ideal in $C[0, 1]$ which is not maximal.

> Is there any $\textbf{closed}$ prime ideal of $C[0, 1]$ which is not maximal?

Any references or ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Note that an ideal in a commutative ring with identity is prime if and only if the quotient ring is an integral domain.

Now consider $C[0,1]$. It is known that the closed ideals in this Banach algebra are all of the form $J_F = \{ f\in C[0,1] \colon {f\vert}_F =0 \}$ for some closed subset $F\subseteq [0,1]$, and $C[0,1]/J_F \cong C(F)$. If $F$ contains two distinct points then $C(F)$ is not an integral domain (just take a "spike" which peaks at $x$ and is supported on a small neighbourhood, and then do likewise for $y$).

The same should be true with $[0,1]$ replaced by any compact Hausdorff space (in the last part of the proof, Urysohn's lemma will produce functions with the desired properties).

---

Update: following requests in the comments, here is a characterization of the closed ideals in $C(X)$, where $X$ is any compact Hausdorff space. Since I am doing this off the top of my head and writing for analysts, I'm going to use excluded middle freely; I'm sure the arguments could be reformulated to reduce or remove this.

Note that I do not need any ${\rm C}^\ast$-algebra theory or functional calculus, and several ingredients below will work for any regular Banach function algebra.$\newcommand{\hull}{\rm hull}$

Given an ideal $J\subseteq C(X)$ let $\ker(J)=\{ x\in X \colon f(x)=0 \,\forall\,f\in J\}$. Given a subset $S\subseteq X$ let $\hull(S)=\{ f\in C(X) \colon f(x)=0 \,\forall\,x\in S\}$. Note that $\ker(J)$ is always closed in $X$ and $\hull(S)$ is always norm-closed in $C(X)$

One can check that $\ker$ and $\hull$ form a Galois connection (adjunction between appropriate posets) but we only need the prosaic fact that $\ker(\hull(J))\supseteq J$. In fact, since $\ker$ of any subset is norm-closed, $\overline{J}\subseteq \ker(\hull(J))$. What I will now show is that this last inclusion is an equality.

So let $a\in \ker(\hull(J))$ and let $\varepsilon>0$. Let $U=\{ x\in X \colon |a(x)| <\varepsilon\}$; this is an open neighbourhood of $\hull(J)$.

Suppose we can produce $b\in J$ such that $b\geq 0$ and $b(x) \geq 1$ for all $x\in X\setminus U$.
Consider $a\cdot (\varepsilon +b)^{-1}b$, which belongs to $J$. Note that if $x\in U$ then
$$
\left\lvert a(x) - \dfrac{a(x)b(x)}{\varepsilon+b(x)} \right\rvert \leq |a(x)| < \varepsilon
$$
and if $x\in X\setminus U$ then
$$
\left\lvert a(x) - \dfrac{a(x)b(x)}{\varepsilon+b(x)} \right\rvert 
= \dfrac{\varepsilon \lvert a(x)\rvert}{\varepsilon+b(x)} \leq |a(x)| \dfrac{\varepsilon}{\varepsilon+1}
$$
Putting these together gives
$$
\lVert a - a\cdot(\varepsilon+b)^{-1}b \rVert_\infty \leq \max\left(\varepsilon, \dfrac{\varepsilon}{\varepsilon+1}\lVert a\rVert_\infty\right).
$$
Since $\varepsilon>0$ is arbitrary, we can conclude that $a\in \overline{J}$.

It remains to produce $b\in J$ with the desired properties, which we do using a routine compactness argument. For each $x\in X\setminus U$, since $x\notin \hull(J)$ we can pick $f_x\in J$ such that $f_x(x)=2$, and then let $U_x$ be an open neighbourhood of $x$ such that $|f_x(y)|^2 > 1$ for all $y\in X\setminus U_x$. By compactness we can extract a finite subcover, relabelled as $U_1,\dots, U_m$ with corresponding $f_1,\dots, f_n \in J$ that satisfy $|f_i(y)|^2 > 1$ for all $y\in U_i$. Now put $b= f_1 \overline{f_1} + \dots + f_n\overline{f_n} \in J$. Clearly $b\geq 0$ and $b(y) \geq 1$ for all $y\in X\setminus U$, as required.

**Remark:** pursuing these ideas further one can show that the Jacobson topology = hull-kernel topology on $X$ (analogue of Zariski topology) coincides with the Gelfand topology. This is definitely not true for general commutative semisimple Banach algebras.

Comment: Thank you so much, Yemen!

Comment: Great answer, but could you please provide a reference for the fact that closed ideals precisely correspond to closed subsets as above?

Comment: (I know Gillman-Jerison but maybe there are other sources that you prefer?)

Comment: Also, concerning your last paragraph - what happens with extremally disconnected compact Hausdorff spaces $X$? I am asking because it seems to me that all prime ideals could be maximal for them. A good example to consider is $X=\beta(\mathbb N)$, the Stone-Čech compactification of the discrete space of natural numbers. Here $C(X)$ is, I believe, isomorphic to $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$, the product of countably many copies of the field of real numbers.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე The fact that (in this setting) closed ideals correspond to closed subsets is often mentioned in texts on noncommutative geometry as an illustration of how the Gelfand transform gives a dictionary between compact Hausdorff spaces and commutative unital Cstar algebras. I don't remember seeing a proof in a book, when I was a PhD student I constructed a proof based on hints seen in sources I don't remember any more. The key is to show that every ideal is the kernel of its hull (i.e. it contains every function that vanishes on the common zero set of all elements of the ideal)

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I haven't thought in detail about closed prime ideals for $C(\beta{\mathbb N})$ but your final claim is incorrect: this Banach algebra is isomorphic to $\ell^\infty({\mathbb N})$. (Since $\beta{\mathbb N}$ is compact all continuous complex-valued functions on it are automatically bounded.)

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე If I can find time/energy later I will consider updating my answer to include an outline of the proof concerning closed ideals in $C(X)$ for $X$ compact Hausdorff.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Your query is related to the spectral synthesis problem for commutative Banach algebras. A closed subset $F$ of the maximal ideal space of a comm. Banach algebra $A$ is said to be an S-set if the only closed ideal with the hull $=F$ is the kernel of $F$. The restatement for $A=C(X)$ is: $F\subseteq X$ is an S-set if the only closed ideal $I$ with $hull(I)=F$ is $J_F$. It happens that every closed subset of $X$ is a set of synthesis.

Comment: @YemonChoi Yes, I forgot that $\mathbb R$ is not compact :)

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Also: you may be looking for Theorem 1.4.6 in https://books.google.ca/books?id=Sp5uwaZsQLAC

Comment: @OnurOktay Thank you for this information. I also believe that the categorical version of the Gelfand duality (that categories of compact Hausdorff spaces and commutative unital $C^*$-algebras are dually equivalent) implies that subobjects of $X$ (which are closed subsets with induced topology, as dictated by morphisms in the category of compact Hausdorff spaces) are in 1-1 correspondence with quotient objects of $C(X)$ (which are necessarily quotients by closed ideals, as dictated by morphisms in the category of $C^*$-algebras).

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე that's an eagle-eye view of the same fact from the top.

Comment: @OnurOktay I believe it can be made rigorous, no? I mean, there *is* this duality of categories, so...

Comment: Professor @მამუკაჯიბლაძე , I thought your argument was already rigorous & impressive.

Comment: @OnurOktay OK thanks. Let's hope it is :)